# Vertical Recyclerview inside horizontal Recyclerview using old views and populating nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am developing an app in which we need vertical Recyclerview inside horizontal Recyclerview. And the vertical Recyclerview have multiple view types. So the problem is, when i scroll down few items and go back up again, only the nested recyclerview is populated with wrong data. Otherwise every other data is correct.

Like in this picture you can see the correct data where recyclerview is gone
[image: pic1]

In this picture you can see the recyclerview is populated with some other object data and showing image when i scroll back up
[image: pic2]

Now i have tried everything setHasStableIds(true) , using same viewpool worsen the situation,getItemId();
But nothing seems to work.

**OUTER RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER**

```
               private ArrayList<BasePostData> basePostDataArrayList;
                    private Context mContext;
                    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool;
                      public PostFragmentListAdapter(ArrayList<BasePostData> basePostDataArrayList, Context mContext) {
                      this.basePostDataArrayList = basePostDataArrayList;
                      this.mContext = mContext;
                       setHasStableIds(true);
              }
                  public static class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                  ImageView profileImage,more;
                  TextView name,user_category,post_category,follow,like,comment,share,description,post_type,highlight;
                  RecyclerView recyclerView;

                HorizontalPostRecyclerview horizontalAdapter;
               public MyviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                   super(itemView);

                   Context context = itemView.getContext();
                   this.comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_comment_textview);
                   this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
                   this.user_category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category);
                   this.post_category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_multiple_categories);
                   this.follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_follow_button);
                   this.like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_like_textview);
                   this.share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_whatsapp_tv);
                   this.profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_pic);
                   this.more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_more_tv);
                   this.description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description_textview);
                   this.recyclerView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_recyclerview);
                   this.post_type= itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_type);
                   this.highlight= itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_highlighted);
                  // recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_list);

               }

            }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout,viewGroup,false);
            MyviewHolder myviewHolder = new MyviewHolder(view);

            return myviewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder viewHolder, int position)
        {

                  StringBuilder post_cat= new StringBuilder();

                  BasePostData basePostData = basePostDataArrayList.get(position);
                  viewHolder.description.setText(basePostData.getDiscription());
                  viewHolder.name.setText(basePostData.getUser());
                  viewHolder.post_type.setText(basePostData.getPost_type());
                  viewHolder.itemView.setTag(position);
                  if (basePostData.getUser_category()!=null){
                      viewHolder.user_category.setText("("+basePostData.getUser_parent_category()+") "+basePostData.getUser_category());
                  }else {
                      viewHolder.user_category.setText(basePostData.getUser_parent_category());
                  }

                  viewHolder.like.setText(String.valueOf(basePostData.getLike())+" Likes");
                  viewHolder.comment.setText(String.valueOf(basePostData.getTotal_comments())+" Comments");

                  for (int i = 0;i<basePostData.getPost_tag().size();i++)
                  {
                      post_cat.append(basePostData.getPost_tag().get(i).getTag()).append(" | ");
                  }

                  viewHolder.post_category.setText(post_cat.toString());

                  Picasso.get()
                          .load(basePostData.getUser_profile_pic())
                          .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_ic)
                          .error(R.drawable.profile_ic)
                          .into(viewHolder.profileImage);


            //--------------------------------highlight answer--------------
            if (basePostData.getHighlight_comment()!=null)
            {
                viewHolder.highlight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.highlight.setText(basePostData.getHighlight_comment().getComment());
            }

             //---------------------------recyclerview for files-------------------------------
            if (basePostData.getFile_type()!=null) {

                viewHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                viewHolder.horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview();
                viewHolder. recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.horizontalAdapter);
                viewHolder.horizontalAdapter.setData(basePostData.getPost_file()); // List of Strings
                viewHolder.horizontalAdapter.setRowIndex(position);
                viewHolder.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                /*
                Log.e("item ",basePostData.getFile_type());
                  viewHolder.   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
              *//* switch (basePostData.getFile_type()){
                   case "Image":
                       viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_IMAGE);
                       viewHolder. recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.horizontalAdapter);
                       break;
                   case "Video":
                       viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_VIDEO);
                       viewHolder. recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.horizontalAdapter);
                       break;
                   case "Document":
                       viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_DOC);
                       viewHolder. recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.horizontalAdapter);
                       viewHolder.horizontalAdapter.setRowIndex(position);

                       break;
               }*//*

               if (basePostData.getFile_type().equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
                   viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_IMAGE);

                 }else if (basePostData.getFile_type().equalsIgnoreCase("video")){
                   viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_VIDEO);
                  }else if (basePostData.getFile_type().equalsIgnoreCase("document"))
                   viewHolder.  horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalPostRecyclerview(basePostData.getPost_file() ,mContext,ConstantsOSH.TYPE_DOC);
                   viewHolder. recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder.horizontalAdapter);
                   viewHolder.horizontalAdapter.setRowIndex(position);
    */            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return basePostDataArrayList.size();
        }
        public void add(ArrayList<BasePostData> basePostDatalist) {
            basePostDataArrayList.addAll(basePostDatalist);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public void clear() {
            basePostDataArrayList.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            BasePostData product = basePostDataArrayList.get(position);
            return product.hashCode();
        }
    }
```

**VERTICAL NESTED RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER**

```
     public class HorizontalPostRecyclerview extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
         private ArrayList<PostFileModel> dataset;
         private Context mContext;
         private int mRowIndex = -1;
         private int viewType;

        public HorizontalPostRecyclerview() {
               setHasStableIds(true);
        }

        public HorizontalPostRecyclerview(ArrayList<PostFileModel> dataset, Context mContext) {
               this.dataset = dataset;
               this.mContext = mContext;
        }
        public HorizontalPostRecyclerview(ArrayList<PostFileModel> dataset, Context mContext,int viewType) {
               this.dataset = dataset;
               this.mContext = mContext;
               this.viewType = viewType;
        }
        public void setRowIndex(int index) {
            mRowIndex = index;
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<PostFileModel> data) {
                        if (dataset != data) {
                            dataset = data;
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
        }



        private class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                    private ImageView imageView,play_btn;
                    private TextView name;

                    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        imageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_image_layout_imageview);
                     //   name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_gallery_name_text);
                       // play_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_gallery_play_btn);
                        }
        }

        private class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                private ImageView imageView,play_btn;
                private TextView name;

                public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    imageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_video_layout_imageview);
                   // name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_gallery_name_text);
                    play_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_video_layout_play_btn);
                }
            }
            private class DocViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                private ImageView imageView,play_btn;
                private TextView name;

                public DocViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    //imageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_gallery_imageview);
                    name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_doc_layout_textview);
                    play_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_doc_layout_playbtn);
                }
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View itemView;
              //  ImageViewHolder holder = new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case ConstantsOSH.TYPE_IMAGE:
                      itemView  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_post_image_layout,viewGroup, false);

                      return new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
                      //  break;

                    case ConstantsOSH.TYPE_DOC:
                        itemView  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_post_doc_layout,viewGroup, false);
                        return new DocViewHolder(itemView);

                 //   break;
                    case ConstantsOSH.TYPE_VIDEO:
                        itemView  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_post_video_layout,viewGroup, false);
                        return new VideoViewHolder(itemView);
                   // break;
                    default:
                        itemView  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_post_image_layout,viewGroup, false);
                        return new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
               // ImageViewHolder holder = (ImageViewHolder) viewHolder;

                switch (dataset.get(i).getFile_type()){
                    case "Image":
                        ImageViewHolder holder = (ImageViewHolder) viewHolder;
                        Picasso.get().load(dataset.get(i).getFile()).error(R.drawable.camera_ic).placeholder(R.drawable.flag_india).into(holder.imageView);
                        holder.itemView.setTag(i);
                  /*      Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()) // Bind it with the context of the actual view used
                                .load(dataset.get(i).getFile()) // Load the image
                                .thumbnail(0.2f) // make use of the thumbnail which can display a down-sized version of the image
                                .into(holder.imageView);
        */
                        break;

                    case "document":
                        DocViewHolder holder2 = (DocViewHolder) viewHolder;
                        holder2.play_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.doc_ic_new);
                        holder2.play_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String[] split = dataset.get(i).getFile().split("post_file/");
                        holder2.name.setText(split[1]);
                        holder2.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder2.itemView.setTag(i);
                        break;

                    case "video":
                        VideoViewHolder holder3 = (VideoViewHolder) viewHolder;
                        long interval = 2000;
                        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(interval).placeholder(R.drawable.camera_ic);
                        Glide.with(holder3.imageView.getContext()).asBitmap()
                                .load(dataset.get(i).getFile())
                                .apply(options)

                                .into(holder3.imageView);
                        holder3.play_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder3.itemView.setTag(i);
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {

                return dataset.size();
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                PostFileModel postFileModel = dataset.get(position);
                return postFileModel.hashCode();
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {

                switch (dataset.get(position).getFile_type()) {
                    case "Image":
                        return ConstantsOSH.TYPE_IMAGE;
                    case "video":
                        return ConstantsOSH.TYPE_VIDEO;
                    case "document":
                        return TYPE_DOC;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I don't see a horizontal recycler view. Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Please Post your code

Comment: I have posted the code @IshitaSinha.

Comment: I have posted the code @PareshRajput

Comment: Please post the xml which contains these recyclerviews because I still don't see any horizontal recycler views in the images.

Comment: The image you can see is an item of horizontal Recyclerview. @IshitaSinha